# 64 bit chrome doesn't work on ubuntu 14.0.4 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, google-chrome, proxy

On my ubuntu desktop, i have both firefox and chrome installed.  firefox works fine with my proxy settings, but chrome won't.  When I try to change the settings in chrome, (advanced settings / network/ change proxy), I get the following error message:

> When running Google Chrome under a supported desktop environment, the
>   system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not
>   supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
>   But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man
>   google-chrome-stable for more information on flags and environment
>   variables.

The proxy settings for my system are correct. Any suggestions on how to get chrome working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use proxy in Chrome you have to change whole system proxy ! on Settings > Network > Network Proxy
change settings here you will get the effects in Chrome. done

Comment: Hi there.  thanks for the response.  That's one of the first things that I tried.  But it still isn't working.

Comment: @dot save your time and use firefox

Comment: that's not an option for me.  I'm going to be doing web programming so i need to test in all browsers.